# RuntimeError no CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: python, pycuda

I have previously import pycuda.autoinit module but when I try to run the code I still get an error

```
      4 # Initialize CUDA
----> 5 cuda.init()
      6 
      7 from pycuda.tools import make_default_context  # noqa: E402
```

RuntimeError: cuInit failed: no CUDA-capable device is detected

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the proper CUDA version installed in your PC, different hardware need different version of CUDA installed.
You can check from: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus